# Laravel 5.5 and mailgun

Tags: laravel-5, mailgun

I have been trying to send emails from my laravel app with mailgun but cant get it to work.

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=(Default SMTP Login from mailgun)
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS= hello@****.*****.me
MAIL_FROM_NAME= Me
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=*****.*****.me
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-10*****************************f
```

mail.php

```
return [
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', '*****.******.me'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@*****.******.me'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Me'),
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
'username' => env('postmaster@*****.******.me'),
'password' => env('************'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('*****.******.me'),
        'secret' => env('key-1******************************f'),
    ],
```

Using this url to test

```
Route::get('/send_test_email', function(){
    Mail::raw('Sending emails with Mailgun and Laravel is easy!', function($message)
    {
        $message->to('finchy70@gmail.com');
    });
});
```

No errors but no emails sent.  Also no activity on my mailgun dashboard.
All my mailgun DNS settings are verified for my domain.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using the value instead of the name in the config for username, password, domain, and secret. Should be

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

And

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

Comment: I have read the docs online and they state that the domain setting in services.php should be the domain you registered with mailgun and the secret the api key they provide you with.  The username and password are the smtp user and password also supplied by mailgun.  Ive tried different combinations of these with no joy.

Comment: Yes but the `env` function accepts the name of the environment variable, not the value. `env('postmaster@*****.******.me')` will return `null` but `env('MAIL_USERNAME')` will return whatever you have defined in your env file for the MAIL_USERNAME key. [details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: Thank you.  That did the trick.  Mailgun now works using api.  Thanks again